# Implementing a c-code loop in python

Tags: python, c, loops

I have a following loop in C:

```
for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
//do something
}
```

I want to write this loop in python. I know that in Python the loop uses the `range(start,end)` format, so I think I should make this somehow as follows:

```
for i in range(0,nvert):
    for j in range(???):
        #do something
```

so my problems are with this:

- how can I determine the range of j?
- how can I do the `j=i++` trick in python (so this loop would act the same as the C-loop above)?

Comment: You can't do the `j=i++` trick in Python unfortunately

Comment: how do you use the indexes? Often in Python, you can drop indexes and iterate over container's items directly e.g., instead of `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i];` in C, you could write `for item in a: item` in Python. If you want a circular buffer; look at [`collections.deque()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the second loop. You can simply include it into the loop:

```
j = nvert - 1
for i in range(0, nvert):
      # do stuff
      j = i
```

**note** that you can simply use `range(nvert)` instead of `range(0, nvert)`

Comment: @Blender I removed the semicolons, I think the `0,` was just copying the OP

Comment: as @Blender said you can tell OP `range(nvert)` is sufficient

Comment: @jamylak can you fix it? Actually, I am not a python programer.